# PHP wont run in terminal with php-cli but runs in apache server

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, cron

I wrote a php script that is intended to run from a bash script in terminal. I installed PHP5 php-cli and php-pear. THe PHP Scripts runs smoothly in apache server using a browser but it does nothing when run from terminal. I also make it to be executable with read and write permission to all. I will put that bash script to run in cron jobs every 5 minutes.

```
#!/usr/bin/php5 -q
<?php
    $file="/var/www/floods/php/indx.txt";
    $indx=file_get_contents($file);
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
    if(!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db("smsgw",$con);

    $acc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts");
    while($fld = mysql_fetch_array($acc)){
        $index[]=$fld['id'];
        $num_reg[]=$fld['num'];
        $loc[]=$fld['location'];    
    }
    if(isset($index)){

    $inbox = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");
    while($fields=mysql_fetch_array($inbox)){
        $id[]=$fields['id'];
        $num_inbox[]=$fields['number'];
        $smsdate[]=$fields['smsdate'];
        $text[]=$fields['text'];    
    }

    $last_indx=count($id);
    $last_num=count($index);


    for($i=0;$i<$last_num;$i++){
        for($j=(int)$indx;$j<$last_indx;$j++){
            if(strcmp($num_inbox[$j],$num_reg[$i])==0){
                $file_save= $num_reg[$i] . ".txt";
                file_put_contents($file_save,$text[$j]);
            }
        }

    }

    }/*End*/

?>
```

Comment: How do you invoke it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Does it not run in any specific way?

Comment: THere are no errors if i run it directly in terminal. I just use `php -f /path/to/file/process.php`. Texts Files should be created after that but it doesnt produce any text file if it run in terminal. But it produced the files when run from the web browser http://localhost/process.php, It should run silently without opening any browser, that's why i'm trying to run it from terminal. :(

Comment: Can you put the crontab line where you are invoking the php scripts?

Comment: Have you tried manually running a PHP script from the commandline with `php -f /path/to/file.php`?  Have you tried confirming that a CLI PHP interperater is installed with `which php` or `php -v`?

Comment: You first need to make sure whether PHP runs from terminal or not. Use something simple such as `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: i used this command `php -v` in terminal its output is this `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 18 2013 23:45:59) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies` when i tried to install php-cli it says that it is installed already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who comments and help. Finally solved the Problem. 
I should specified the exact path where to save the text files.
`$file_save= $num_reg[$i] . ".txt";` should be like this
`$file_save="/path/where/to/save". $num_reg[$i] . ".txt";`